# Nuget package published to public and private feed

Tags: nuget, azure-devops, continuous-deployment

We want to build a csproj project.
Because we will be using the package internally for development **and**
deliver it to an external company too we decided to create 2 packages/2 feeds.
Packages are created using the csproj file.

- For the public feed we build using Release configuration.
- For the private feed we build using Debug configuration + Symbols.
  ***This will output 2 packages (*.symbols.nupkg and *.nupkg)***

o What is advised to maintain code privacy but still have a good developer experience?
o What do I publish to the feed for Debug?
o Can I install both public/private package somehow, if not, what is advised?
o How does nuget decide on priority if I have both public and private feed in VS?
o If we start replacing the references by assembly with the nuget package and package that project, will it include the dependencies in the nuspec file?

Comment: What do you mean debug the feed? And no mastter for public feed or private feed, you can use `nuget push` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/cli-ref-push) to push your nuget packages to the two feeds.

Comment: I meant; which nuget packages do I publish to the private (debug) feed.

Answer (score 0):

- **If the external company can access to the public feed**, just use the public feed can save your energies.

  You can push your nuget packages to one place (the public feed), it will be convenient to manage and maintain the package, and developers from the external company can also get the package from the public feed. And it’s also the common way to use.
- **If the external company can not access to the public feed, or you just want to manage the package in two separate feeds**

  There will have the questions as you list (the main point is **packages in private feed and public feed are equal**):

  Any of the packages (`name.symbols.nupkg` and `name.nupkg`) can be pushed to the private feed since the contents of the two packages are same. The only difference is the names.

  You can not install the package both from public feed and private feed. After install the package from one feed, when you search the package in the other feed, it will show the package has installed. And it’s the same result to install the package from any of the two feeds.